# Wp7: Doesn't play song with media element

Tags: windows-phone-7, mediaelement

I want to play audio song in my Windows Phone 7 application.

For playing song I am using a `MediaElement`.

and my C# code is

```
MediaElement song = new MediaElement();
song.Source = new Uri("Live Url of audio song", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
LayoutRoot.Children.Add(song);
song.AutoPlay = False;
song.Play();
```

It does't show any error and does not play.

Comment: Checking the obvious - but does `Uri` point to the right place? I'd also set `AutoPlay` to `false` *before* setting the source.

Comment: This Uri is my variable...i mean string Uri;this is not an error

Comment: Have you tried on the phone emulator AND an actual phone?  I ask because I did you you are doing with a wav file, and could not get it to work on the emulator but works fine on my real phone...

Comment: ya now its working  on my actual phone but another problem is created.This code is on button click event so when i pressed button it wiil paly song but when i pause the song than after try to play song so it will give exception in LayoutRoot.Children.Add(song);
line...and Exception is "Element is already the child of another element".how can i solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

The media element need to load its media before you can call Play(), otherwise nothing will happen. The event MediaOpened is fired when the media is loaded.

```
myMediaElement.MediaOpened += (o, args) => myMediaElement.Play();
```

Answer (score 0):

I got Solution

i take medeiElement in XAML part..

```
 <MediaElement Name="myMediaElement" 
                      AutoPlay="True" 
                      />
```

C# code is

```
 Uri path;
 path = new Uri("/VodafoneAugmentedReality;component/Images/pause.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);

myMediaElement.Source = new Uri(Uri, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
myMediaElement.Play();
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a bug, whenever you set AutoPlay="False" so just dont do that and dont set the Source in the xaml if you dont want AutoPlay

```
    <MediaElement Name="mediaElementTones" Volume="1" ></MediaElement>
```

Then use 
in code

```
            Uri keypadUri = new Uri("./Resources/Sounds/dtmf" + keyPressed + ".wav", UriKind.Relative);
            mediaElementTones.Source = keypadUri;
            mediaElementTones.Play();
```